# Load OpenXML content in Django admin TextField keeping styles

Tags: python, django-admin, docx, redactor.js

I'm trying to use **Django 1.8 admin interface** + [RedactorJS](https://imperavi.com/redactor/) (via [django-wysiwyg-redactor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wysiwyg-redactor/)) to load a doc file into Django model's field, enabled with the RedactorEditor plugin. On other words: **allow the user to load and modify a simple DOC file using a textarea from the Django admin.**

So far, I've been able to read the doc (using [oodocx](https://github.com/evfredericksen/oodocx)), transform it to OpenXML string using [lxml](http://lxml.de/), and store that string in model's field of type Text.

Besides, I can use the RedactorEditor widget to load that field, and have a toolbar TinyMCE style, to modify the content of the loaded DOC file.

The problem is I lose all the styles. And as a picture worths a thousand words, here it comes

**My original word file**

[image]

**How the field looks like in the Django admin field**

[image]

And this is the content of the text field, as Unicode OpenXML string:

```
u'<w:body xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/><w:jc w:val="center"/><w:rPr/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr/><w:t>Text text text text text text text</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/><w:rPr/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr/></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/><w:rPr><w:b/><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:color w:val="800000"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:color w:val="800000"/></w:rPr><w:t>RED TEXT RED TEXT RED TEXT RED TEXT</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/><w:rPr/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr/></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/><w:rPr/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr/></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="1"/></w:numPr><w:rPr/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr/><w:t>POINT 1</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="1"/></w:numPr><w:rPr/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr/><w:t>POINT 2</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="0"/><w:numId w:val="1"/></w:numPr><w:rPr/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr/><w:t>POINT 3</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:sectPr><w:type w:val="nextPage"/><w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/><w:pgMar w:left="1134" w:right="1134" w:header="0" w:top="1134" w:footer="0" w:bottom="1134" w:gutter="0"/><w:pgNumType w:fmt="decimal"/><w:formProt w:val="false"/><w:textDirection w:val="lrTb"/></w:sectPr></w:body>'
```

So, **how could I make the redactorjs Django widget to understand the OpenXML format and apply the styles? Should I use another different Javascript editor? Try to write my own redactorJS plugin? A different approach, maybe?**

Answer (score 1):

Solved: transformed the OpenXML content of the DOC file to HTML using [python-docx](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). After that, just load the HTML in the redactorjs editor